# asp.net grid show total rows and actual rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, gridview

we have 3 tiers asp.net web application.
we have some scenarios where the user query can return many rows to be view on the grid.
so our solution was to restrict the number of rows that the ado.net dataAdapter Fill method can return.
now the user want to know the real total number of records that actually reside in the DB for it's grid query (for each grid query) and the actual number of records that he see.
some query are sql command type text and others are store procedures.

the middle tier and data tier are on 2 different machines.

what is the solution for this requirment if we are using now .net1.1 framework and next version will be with .net4 framework?
(we are using now microsoft sql server 2005)

Comment: just check this link : [ASP.NET Extended Grid Control](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/04/aspnet-extended-grid-control.html) which may satify you need

Comment: hey this will work in 1.1 ......i think that

Comment: does it work with store procedure to fetch the data, also?